# CSS filter one background image on an element that has multiple background images

Tags: css, css-filters

I've got an element with this css. It works great, but I want to blur the image that is set to cover. I can't find a way to apply filters to just one background image. I realize I could probably set it up with `::before` or `::after`, but I was really hoping there was a clean solution to make it part of the css one-liner here. I did some research, but didn't find any information about this. Is there some fancy css wizardry nowadays that can do this?

```
background: url($img) center/contain no-repeat, url($img) center/cover;
```

I'm hoping to be able to do something like this:

```
background: url($img) center/contain no-repeat, url($img) center/cover blur(20px);
```

Comment: In a far future you will be able to do such magic, until now your only solution is pseudo elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want can be done like below using [`filter()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#FilterCSSImageValue)

```
background: 
  url($img) center/contain no-repeat,
  filter(url($img), blur(20px)) center/cover;
```

But no browser support for this right now: https://caniuse.com/css-filter-function

Comment: Hey, Safari is supporting now!